# Markers won't appear on GeoChart, but the map displays just fine

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I'm having trouble getting Geochart Markers to load onto a map. The script provided by Google renders a blank map on my website, but the markers and map appear as they should on jsfiddle. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

  function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', 'Collaborator'],
    ['Detroit', "text here"],
    ['Cleveland', "text here"],
    ['Joondalup', "text here"],
    ['Wanaka', "text here"]
    ['Liverpool', "text here"],
    ['Styria', "text here"],
    ['Edwardsville', "text here"],
    ['Austin', "text here"],
    ['Houston', "text here"],
    ['Stockholm', "text here"],
    ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'world',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    backgroundColor: '#252426',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['blue']},
    magnifyingGlass: {enable: false},
    defaultColor: '#f1910e',
    enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
     };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! Apparently google now requires an API key to display markers on geocharts. Here's the modified, functional, script.
The second line is the only change.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE" async="" defer="defer"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

function drawMarkersMap() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['City', 'Collaborator'],
['Detroit', "text here"],
['Cleveland', "text here"],
['Joondalup', "text here"],
['Wanaka', "text here"]
['Liverpool', "text here"],
['Styria', "text here"],
['Edwardsville', "text here"],
['Austin', "text here"],
['Houston', "text here"],
['Stockholm', "text here"],
]);

var options = {
region: 'world',
displayMode: 'markers',
backgroundColor: '#252426',
colorAxis: {colors: ['blue']},
magnifyingGlass: {enable: false},
defaultColor: '#f1910e',
enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
};

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

API keys are free through google, provided your website isn't receiving too much traffic. You'll need to register a "browser key". Here's a link to get it set up:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Any suggestions for enabling this to use an environment variable or something for the api key so that the api key isn't hard-coded (which is a security risk)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625587/how-do-i-securely-use-google-api-keys

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1537), it seems like your network might be blocking the geocoding. The GeoChart needs to geocode the markers in order to know where to draw them.

Check this related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263660/display-regions-in-google-maps-api) and [example from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/gerryster/4242467).

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Foo Factor'],
    ['US-IL', 200],
    ['US-IN', 300],
    ['US-IA', 20],
    ['US-RI', 150]
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: "US", resolution: "provinces"});
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I found a number of console errors which seemed to be a result of my adblocker.

After disabling the adblocker, there was only one console error, which I think could be the problem:

"Google Maps API Error: MissingKeyMapError"

I generated an API key, but now I'm not sure how/where to insert it into the script.