# Google play console gives security alert - Vulnerable

Tags: google-play-console, android-security

Google play console gives security alert - Vulnerable

Can anyone have idea why is it giving security alert

Here are the builld.gradle file the library which I’m using in app.

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “************”
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 126
        versionName "2.14.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        resConfigs "en"    // Commented because need to support MultiLanguage
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }

    api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    api 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    api 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3'
    api 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'
```

Alert Play Console is showing

```
Vulnerable locations:

**.**.*********.****.SliderImage.YouTubeVideo->onActivityResult
**.**.*********.****.SliderImage.YouTubeVideo->onCreate
**.**.*********.****.LocationAndContactActivity->setupAutocompleteFragment
**.**.*********.****.LocateOnGoogleMapActivity->setupAutocompleteFragment
**.**.*********.****.MediaDetailsActivity$13$1$1->run
**.**.*********.****.MediaDetailsActivity$6->onClick
**.**.*********.****.MediaDetailsActivity->assignYoutubeThumbnail
**.**.*********.****.adapter.MediaAdapter$3->onClick
**.**.*********.****.adapter.MediaAdapter->onBindViewHolder
**.**.*********.****.CustomPages_Adapter$4->onClick
**.**.*********.****.CustomPages_Adapter->onBindViewHolder
**.**.*********.****.adapter.CustomPagesAdapter$4->onClick
**.**.*********.****.adapter.CustomPagesAdapter->onBindViewHolder
**.**.*********.****.ProductDetailsActivity$11->onClick
**.**.*********.****.ProductDetailsActivity$26$1$1->run
**.**.*********.****.ProductDetailsActivity->onCreate
**.**.*********.****.WebPostDetailActivity->setupAutocompleteFragment
**.**.*********.****.adapter.WebPostAdapter$4->onClick
**.**.*********.****.adapter.WebPostAdapter->onBindViewHolder
**.**.*********.****.FourthStageActivity->setupAutocompleteFragment
```

Comment: Can you show the full warning you are getting?

Comment: Google play will tell you exactly whats wrong with it! You should see a list of all the classes google deems as unsafe!

Comment: @MohanKumar I have added the warning i am getting

Comment: @kriskotooBG Still now it was working fine, After soo months it gives me the security alert, I have started facing this problem when i have migrate to androidx and upgraded the google library

Comment: Are you using any services? like APIs or databses? if yes, you might have your API access keys exposed! check for any exposed keys in those classes!

Comment: @kriskotooBG From where and how i will get to know whether API keys are exposed

Comment: @kriskotooBG One Alert is for maps which i'am using in app and second one is for youtube thumbnail in which i'am not using any youtube api for that

Comment: @AviSoni This link should help you: https://developer.android.com/google/play/asi
:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205202/discussion-between-avi-soni-and-kriskotoo-bg).

Answer (score 0):

This happens usually when your API keys are exposed which means you are using API keys directly into application code. so anyone can just extract your apk and get the API keys easily and exhaust your usage quotas.

**FIX**

There are several methods to hide your API keys. one of the best method is storing it in external server and retrieving it.
You may also use other methods too from the link below,

1. [Methods with explanations](https://hackernoon.com/mobile-api-security-techniques-682a5da4fe10)
2. [Restricting API keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625963/9882579)
3. [Encryption methods](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android)

Comment: I'am using Api key from resource file, so is it not secure?

Comment: @AviSoni Not secure

Comment: Can you help me with the step's to make Api Secure?

Comment: Are using external server for data fetching ?