# How could I restrict Google Directions API access for an Amazon skill?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, alexa-skills-kit, api-key, directions

I have created an Alexa Skill that uses the Google Directions API. I am only using returned JSON data. According the API documentation, the API key must be available to the public. I want the API key to be used only for my Amazon Alexa skill. How could I restrict this API access for the Amazon Alexa skill?

Comment: Keys should always be restricted, keys for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 must be publicly available (they are on a public web page), but server keys (which are required for web services) don't **have** to be public the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still am confused on how to execute this. I was previously referring to this question for direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625587/how-do-i-securely-use-google-api-keys

Comment: If you are using a web service, you aren't using the Google Maps Javascript API v3.